# Add text in Qlabel

Tags: python, pyqt

I am showing a message into a Qlabel and I want to append the messages:

```
if A>B:
   text_1=('As<sub>min</sub>')
else:
   text_1=(' ')

if A>C:
  text_2=(' A>C')
else:
  text_2=(' ')

self.ui.label.setText('message' + '\n' +text_1 + '\n' + text_2)
```

But the message displayed looks like this

```
message
As<sub>min</sub>
A>C
```

instead of

message

As  <sub>min</sub>

A>C

My problem is when I try to display the subscript, it doesn`t show

Comment: Note: Do not copy code that is clearly not the code you use since, for example, your initial code had many typos. I have corrected them because the error you indicate had nothing to do with the typos but in other cases they could close your post for that reason.

Comment: thanks, I tried to put a simple example of my code, only for showing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `<br>` if you want to do a line break instead of "\n" which is for plain text.

```py
self.ui.label.setText("<br>".join(["message", text_1, text_2]))
```

Comment: I believe that the problem of the OP is about the html parsing, which Qt is not able to recognize in `AutoText` mode if it doesn't begin with a recognized tag.

Comment: @musicamante The problem of the OP is that it is combining plain text with HTML, and in that case Qt will use the plain text if there is any character that only has the plain text like "\n"

Comment: Uhm, right. The problem partially exists though, as I recall that I had a similar situation with some tags not recognized which resulted in full plain text even without any line breaks (but with correct syntax though).

Comment: @musicamante Qt only supports a subset of HTML4 tags, maybe you used the tags that it doesn't support or that were introduced in HTML5

Comment: I am pretty sure that they were part of the supported subset, unfortunately I don't remember the exact situation (and, my bad, I didn't take notice of it as I should have), as I was focused on another task and I just dismissed it as a possible bug in the parser that I worked around it by adding the basic `<html>...</html>` tags.